# iOS JavaScriptCore function with `init` in signature

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore and some existing JavaScript code to power the model of my app. Because the JavaScript code is in use by other products, I need to avoid changing any of it, if possible.

The problem that I'm encountering is that the JavaScript expects a method called `initBlockClass` to be defined on one of the objects being provided by the Swift portion of the app. This is a problem because functions with a signature that start with `init` are considered initializers (not what I need) and are exported to the JavaScript with a slightly modified signature.

Is there a way to work around this without modifying the JavaScript?